# PHP Storm - Symfony2 plugin error

Tags: php, symfony, phpstorm

I installed Symfony2 plugin for PHP Storm, but I am getting this error in PHP Storm event log:

```
Could not initialize class fr.adrienbrault.idea.symfony2plugin.stubs.indexes.RoutesStubIndex
```

Why is that? Did I miss something? Any other dependency is required?

Comment: Seems that support for PhpStorm7 is not done any-more: `0.11.x: PhpStorm 8
0.10.x: PhpStorm 7 (no support)
0.9.x: PhpStorm 6 (no support)` what version are you using? Moreover, be sure to have your cache generated.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is that?

A message that a class could not be initialized (Java)

> Did I miss something?

The plugin is perhaps incompatible with your PHPStorm version, but from the error message you'Ve given alone, I can't say that you missed something parcticularly.

> Any other dependency is required?

That normally produce more output.

It perhaps helps if you take a look in the log of the IDE, see the `system\log` subdirectory in your PHPStorm user folder (`.WebIde80`).

Otherwise you could double check the plugin now is disabled. If not disable it. Restart PHPStorm, then enable it and restart PHPStorm again. Check if you see some backtrace and if it says that the plugin has been automatically disabled.

If that is not the case, contact the developer of the plugin for your support options, most likely the developer is interested in a report, get your PHPStorm version details together and add the information from the logfiles if related to the plugin.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I already tried installing, uninstalling, enabling disabling and restarting IDE. Didnt help. I found a stack trace but I dont think it will help

Comment: Well at least it will help when you report the problem with the project. Also you can search for the error given in the stack trace. Double check you're using the correct PHPStorm version and the correct plugin version: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7219?pr=idea -- https://github.com/Haehnchen/idea-php-symfony2-plugin/issues

Comment: `2014-12-23 13:49:24,363 [1763363]  ERROR - aemon.impl.PassExecutorService - PhpStorm 8.0.1 
 at fr.adrienbrault.idea.symfony2plugin.routing.RouteHelper.getAllRoutes(RouteHelper.java:776)
 at fr.adrienbrault.idea.symfony2plugin.navigation.TwigFoldingBuilder.attachPathFoldingDescriptors(TwigFoldingBuilder.java:103)
 at fr.adrienbrault.idea.symfony2plugin.navigation.TwigFoldingBuilder.buildFoldRegions(TwigFoldingBuilder.java:41)`

Maybe it will help a little bit. Somethings wrong with my routing. It seems like plugin cant find my routes

Comment: Check your PHPStorm version that it is actually 8.0.2. And if it's something with your routes I really suggest to create the smallest possible example to reproduce the issue and report this to the plugin project.

Comment: it was 8.0.1 before, I updated to 8.0.2, disabled and enabled plugin, there is no more errors

Comment: there you go, PHPStorm version incompatibility.

Answer (score 0):

What about checking project ownership / permissions?
I changed my project ownership and now it's working.